# Difference between mkfs -t ext4 and mkfs.ext4

Tags: mkfs

Is there a difference between `sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdb` and `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb`?
Or is the latter just an alias of the former?

Answer (score 17):

`mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdb` first runs the generic `[/usr]/sbin/mkfs` command, which is a wrapper that will select the correct filesystem-specific mkfs binary (in this case, the `[/usr]/sbin/mkfs.ext4`) according to the value of the `-t` option, and will pass the rest of the command line to it.

`mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb` simply skips the wrapper and calls the filesystem-specific binary directly.

From the `mkfs(8)` man page:

> In actuality, `mkfs` is simply a front-end for the various filesystem builders  (`mkfs.fstype`) available under Linux. The filesystem-specific builder is searched for via your PATH environment setting only. Please see the filesystem-specific builder manual pages for further details.

Comment: It seems that `mkfs.ext4` actually runs `mke2fs`. If I run the man page: `man mkfs.ext4` it shows me the `mke2fs` man page and says: *If mke2fs is run as mkfs.XXX (i.e., mkfs.ext2, mkfs.ext3, or mkfs.ext4) the option -t XXX is implied; ...*

Comment: @EdgarMagallon You're correct. At least on my system, `mkfs.ext4` is a symbolic link to `mke2fs`. It might be a hard link in some other distributions, or a wrapper script. But if you remove `mkfs.ext4` leaving only `mke2fs`, then `mkfs -t ext4` stops working because it specifically looks for `mkfs.<value_of_-t_option>`.

Comment: @telcoM @EdgarMagallon that is common practice (see `xz`, `mtools` or `busybox` for example). The program finds out the name it's been called by and sets the internal behaviour accordingly. See [these source lines](https://github.com/tytso/e2fsprogs/blob/master/misc/mke2fs.c#L1343), where it happens for `mke2fs`.

Comment: telcoM Oh, that's true, in my case it is a hard link (I hadn't noticed that). @EduardoTrápani that makes sense now, I was thinking that `mke2fs` was another different tool.

Answer (score 11):

Since `mkfs -t xyz` just runs `mkfs.xyz` you are running two programs instead of one.

Anyway, `mkfs` should no longer be used. From the [manpage](https://man.archlinux.org/man/mkfs.8):

> The mkfs frontend is deprecated in favour of filesystem specific `mkfs.<type>` utils.

Answer (score 3):

Citing the documentation [man mkfs](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs):

> In actuality, **mkfs** is simply a front-end for the various file system builders (**mkfs.*fstype***) available under Linux. ...

So I expect that `mkfs -t ext4` will call `mkfs.ext4`.

Answer (score -3):

The **mkfs.ext4** command is a specific command for creating ext4 filesystems, and it is essentially equivalent to **mkfs -t ext4**. It is provided as a convenience to **make it easier** to create ext4 filesystems without having to specify the -t option each time.

Comment: actually `mkfs -t ext4` is the one that's supposedly convenient